# How to pass the values to point json object in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, I would like to fetch the Firstname based on active language selected using React

language file.Json

```
{"activelanguage":"English",
  "English":
       {
        "id":1,         
        "first_name": "First name",
        "last_name": "Last name",
        "email": "Email",
        "password": "Password",
        "mobile": "Mobile Phone"
      },
    "தமிழ்":{
          "id":2,
          "first_name": "முதல் பெயர்",
          "last_name": "கடைசி பெயர்",
          "email": "மின்னஞ்சல்",
          "password": "கடவுச்சொல்",
          "mobile": "கைபேசி எண்"
      }
    }
```

What i have used in the ReactCode;

```
var activelanguage="English";
var firstName=languagelist.{activelanguage}.first_name;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to point to the property of an object, you can use strings. For example:

```
var activeLanguage="English";
var firstName = languagelist[activeLanguage]?.first_name || defaultCase; // <- just add a default case.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var firstName=languagelist[activelanguage].first_name;
```

See [this post](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp) for details